# SQLServer // Tabelas

Tags: sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Criei um DataBase e nele está contido duas tabelas, coloquei usei o script:

Tabela Cliente

```
Create table Cliente( 
    Cod_Cliente int Primary key 
    NOME Varchar(50)
    SOBRENOME Varchar (50)
) 
GO
```

Tabela Porte da Empresa

```
Create table Porte_Empresa( 
   PEQUENO float 
   MÉDIO float 
   GRANDE float
)
GO
```

BD: `Create Database CADASTRO`

A questão é que não estou vendo as tabelas no lado esquerdo quando faço a expansão do BD mesmo dando refresh.

Comment: Você consegue usar `Select` nas tabelas? Posta o script que vc usou!

Comment: Posta o Scrip que vc usou para tentar criar o banco e a tabela.

Comment: Infelizmente não.
Criei duas tabelas:Cliente e Porte da Empresa.
Script da tabela Cliente:
Create table Cliente(
Cod_Cliente int Primary key
NOME Varchar(50)
SOBRENOME Varchar (50)
)
GO

Tabela Porte da Empresa

Create table Porte_Empresa(
PEQUENO float
MÉDIO float
GRANDE float
)
GO

BD: Create Database CADASTRO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você utilizou essa ordem quando executou a consulta, provavelmente suas tabelas devem esta na `DATABASE master`.
Se você executa uma consulta sem setar uma DB, por padrão ela adotara os comandos a DATABASE chamada master.

É necessário utilizar o `USE nomedadb`, veja na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue Código:

```
CREATE DATABASE Cadastro
GO

USE Cadastro

Create table Cliente( 
    Cod_Cliente int Primary key IDENTITY,
    NOME Varchar(50),
    SOBRENOME Varchar (50)
) 
GO 

Create table Porte_Empresa( 
   PEQUENO float, 
   MÉDIO float,
   GRANDE float
)
GO
```

Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: Excelente,Paulo.Muito obrigado!! Fiz a exclusão do banco(CADASTRO) e das tabelas e criei novamente utilizando o ''USE''. Não sabia desse comando,toda vez que for necessário criar um DB é obrigatório o ''USE''?

Comment: Toda vez que vc for executar uma consulta, vc tem que setar uma banco para receber "tal consulta".  Para seta-lo a palavra chave é o `USE`. Vamos supor que após criar suas tabelas, vc crie um novo Banco sem fechar a consulta, as tabelas que vc criar a seguir serão armazenadas dentro da anterior, caso não utilize o USE.

Comment: Entendido, muito grato pela explicação.

Comment: Vlw, tamos aê!!! Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como útil, caso tenha servido.

Comment: @EricRosário, se resolveu o problema, marca a resposta como aceita ;)

Comment: Feito. Obrigado,galera!